# How to hide a rows in table with jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFwZR.jpg

Here i have a table and i need to hide all rows (tr), where Course (table's td) is 2 (for example), and left other rows. And second case is to left all exept where course is 2 (for example). Please, can you suggest me how to do it correct?

Comment: Can you post the markup you're working with and what you've tried so far?

Comment: but, it doesn't work, of course

Comment: Can you post your table html....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Should work fine..

```
$('#yourTableID tr').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim()=='2'){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: untested code... Please test and revert back with the result.. I dont have anything to try my code on... :(

Comment: some minutes later, ive found a solution
if ($(this).children(':nth-child(2)').text() == 1){
   $(this).hide();
}                   
but your code works too! thanks alot!